# How to read byte[]-image from database and convert to displayable image with JPA and PrimeFaces/JSF?

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using an byte array `byte[]` to store images in my databse, using JPA:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(length=16777000)
private byte[] image;
```

This is how I upload the images, before storing them in the database:

```
public void uploadFile(org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent event) {
    byte[] img = event.getFile().getContents();
    // and so on...
}
```

Then, I am reading the image from the database and want to display it using PrimeFaces/JSF. Something like:

```
<p:galleria value="#{bean.images}" var="image"
    panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
        <p:graphicImage name="image"
            alt="Some description..." title="Some title..." />
</p:galleria>
```

To do that, I need to convert the `byte[]` array back to a displayable image. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: John, in future JSF questions about problems which are **not** answerable with JLS nor reproducible using a plain Java SE application class with `main()` method, do **not** use [java] tag. If your question however is, then you should instead question the relevance of Java EE related tags such as [jsf] and [jpa].

Comment: OK BalusC, I will take care in future.

Comment: But anyway, there was an answer to my question and I would like to see it...

Comment: That answer didn't make any sense. It just writes the `byte[]` to a local disk file system file in unnecessarily convoluted way via `ImageIO`. The answerer didn't seem to understand anything from the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks anyway.